# How to set the default package in flow3 framework?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-flow

I am new to Flow3 . I have successfully managed to install the flow3 2.2 version and I have managed to implement a custom package as well. But thing is, I am unable to change the default package from Typo3.Welcome to my custom package.

Steps I performed

```
./flow package:deactivate TYPO3.Welcome
```

Changed  Routes.yaml files

```
-
 name: 'Welcome screen'
 uriPattern: 'testproject/index'
   defaults:
     '@package':    'TYPO3.Index'
     '@controller': 'coffeebean'
     '@action':     'index'
     '@format':     'html'
 -    
 name: 'Welcome screen'
 uriPattern: 'testproject/new'
 defaults:
  '@package':    'TYPO3.Index'
  '@controller': 'coffeebean'
  '@action':     'new'
  '@format':     'html'
```

But still when try to access http://tutorial.local/ from my local machine it is pointing to Typo3.Flow . Can any one please tell me how can override this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok that was pretty straight forward !!!

In order to set your custom package as default package just change the Routes.yaml file add these lines on top of it. -

```
`name: 'Welcome screen'
  uriPattern: '' //Set the URL Pattern as empty to load the custom package as index.
    defaults:
      '@package':    'TYPO3.Index'
      '@controller': 'coffeebean'
      '@action':     'index'
      '@format':     'html'

-    
  name: 'Welcome screen'
  uriPattern: 'testproject/new'
  defaults:
    '@package':    'TYPO3.Index'
    '@controller': 'coffeebean'
    '@action':     'new'
    '@format':     'html'`
```